# Bosonic commutation relations for force carriers?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra, bosons

Why are force carriers bosons?

The easiest answer that I can give myself is that the gauge field $A_\mu$ is introduced like this:

$$ \partial_\mu \rightarrow D_\mu = \partial_\mu+ieA_\mu, $$

so it needs to transform like the derivative $\partial_\mu$ which we know transforms via (simple) Lorentz transformations $\partial_\nu = \Lambda^\mu_\nu \partial_\mu$ and is hence of even spin.

This is opposed to a spinor $\psi$ which would transform as $\psi \rightarrow \Lambda_{1/2}\psi$, such as to leave e.g. the Dirac action Lorentz invariant i.e. $\bar{\psi}D_\mu\psi \rightarrow (\bar{\psi}\Lambda_{1/2}^T)(\Lambda D_\mu)(\Lambda_{1/2}\psi) \rightarrow \mathrm{other \,steps} \sim \Lambda^T \Lambda = 1$.

**Question**

If I start with a field theory whose lagrangian goes like $\propto \partial_\mu\psi$, I get the gauge field $A_\mu$ from assuming a local group symmetry of $\psi$, e.g. $SU(N)$. Because the phase factor of $\psi$ would now be $x$ dependent $e^{\phi(x)}$, the derivative $\partial_\mu$ acts on it and this term needs to be "cancelled" by the gauge transformation of the gauge field $A_\mu$.

It is then easy to see that $A_\mu$ is an element of the Lie algebra of the group $G$ (here, $SU(N)$) and can be written in terms of its generators: $A_\mu = \sum_\alpha T_\alpha A^\alpha _\mu$.

Is it possible to get bosonic commutation relations for $A_\mu$ from the commutation relations of the generators $T_\alpha$?

Comment: just a clarification: force carriers, i.e. dp/dt transfers, can happen in interactions with all the particles in the standard model table. You are asking for the identification of gauge bosons to the three  (four?) known classical forces, no?

Comment: Yes. U(1) local phase symmetry entails the existence of 1 gauge field, the photon. Why is that a boson?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461800/

Comment: because it exists in the mathematical symmetry and is the simplest mathematically candidate for modeling the interaction in lowest order, and thus it is identified with the force the U(1) describes. and it fits the data.

Comment: Ok but I am asking how to generalise with with a number N of gauge fields? Can we justify the bosonic nature mathematically?

Comment: If you're asking why spin $1$ fields have bosonic statistics, that's because of the spin-statistics theorem. (The commutation relations of the $A_\mu^\alpha$, which are infinite-dimensional operators acting on the QFT Hilbert space, are not at all the same as the commutation relations of the $T_\alpha$, which are just low-dimensional matrices.)

Comment: I am asking  if there is a way to infer the statistics obeyed by the field based on its transformations.

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m saying. The spin statistics theorem is exactly what relates properties under Lorentz transformations with whether a field is bosonic or fermionic.

Comment: Because fermionic massless gauge fields like gravitini cannot give rise to long range potentials.

Comment: I think that the answer to your last question is negative: $A_\mu$ may be governed by topological field theory, they may not represent a localized particle to be called a boson, and it is impossible to deduce that from interaction with matter terms only.

Comment: OK. @CosmasZachos how does masslessness and long range potentials get in the picture of spin and statistics?

Comment: You cannot get a long range potential from the infrared limit of a one-fermion exchange, is all. It is an elimination argument.

Comment: Thanks. If someone wants to combine this with @knzhou last comment I'll happily accept it as an answer.